# Find a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb C)$ which does not contain the semisimple and unipotent parts

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Find a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb C)$ which does not contain the semisimple and unipotent parts of all its elements.

**Attempt:** According to the theory, there is no chance to find one counterexample in the family of closed subgroups. I can't find good not closed subgroups, because the one I try to think of are created via relations on eigenvalues (e.g all eigenvalues are integer powers of some trascendent $\alpha$). These kind of relations turn out to be preserved in the semisimple and unipotent parts.

Comment: This is a typical exercise, e.g.,  in [Humphreys](https://books.google.at/books?id=7hTTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=Find+a+subgroup+of+GL(2,ℂ)+which+does+not+contain+the+semisimple+and+unipotent+parts+of+all+its+elements.&source=bl&ots=PaKEh9l_34&sig=OPz_AWy4m3aJKGfGmKMeVwIkoi4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn88mirfjYAhUKZ1AKHcG_CJkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Find%20a%20subgroup%20of%20GL(2%2Cℂ)%20which%20does%20not%20contain%20the%20semisimple%20and%20unipotent%20parts%20of%20all%20its%20elements.&f=false). What did you try?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes it comes from there, but I can't solve it!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't know what to try since all the subgroups I can think of have some kind of relations on the eigenvalues, which is bad. It can't be algebraic group or it is closed, it can't be finite, I would like it to be small like 1PS but have not many examples in mind.

Comment: Hint: Try to find an infinite cyclic subgroup with this property.

Comment: @MoisheCohen maybe my answer is correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the group generated by \begin{bmatrix}
    e & 1 \\
    0 & e
\end{bmatrix}

None of its elements but $I_2$ are semisimple nor unipotent.

Comment: They all are unipotent, are they not?

Comment: @PseudoNeo is it ok now? :)

Comment: This matrix is semisimple (since it has two distinct eigenvalues).

Comment: @MoisheCohen hopefully this is right now!

Comment: Yes, now it is correct. Can you prove this?

Comment: This is obvious, they have no 1 eigenvalues since they are powers of $e$, and they are not semisimple since the right up corner is never $0$, so they are likea Jordan form (more or less)